# Form submission redirects to custom action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

I have a form in my index, the form posts to a url corresponding to an action which I have created myself. My index is '/instructions' and upon submitting the form, I would like to be redirected to '/instructions/quick_run' with the form as params.

Currently I have:

instructions_controller.rb

```
class InstructionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @instruction = Instruction.all
  end

  def quick_run
    @analysis_options = params
  end
end
```

index.html.slim

```
= form_with url: "/instructions/quick_run" do |form| 
  p = form.file_field :text_file, as: :file, accept: '.txt'
  p = form.submit
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :instructions, only: [:index,:new,:edit,:destroy] do
    collection do
      post 'quick_run'
      get 'quick_run'
    end
  end
```

Upon hitting submit, I can see a Started POST "/instructions/quick_run" along with the file input passed as a param, however I am not being redirected to "/instructions/quick_run". I am also notified of instructions/quick_run.html.slim being rendered, however it is not displayed and the url is still "/instructions"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using rails 5.x, correct?

By default, rails 5 assumes you'll use Ajax (javascript) to submit requests and does not do local post event.    see:  http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-with

To change this behavior, update your form with `local: true`

```
= form_with url: "/instructions/quick_run", local: true do |form| 
p = form.file_field :text_file, as: :file, accept: '.txt'
p = form.submit
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, rails 5.2, ruby 2.3.3. And your answer did exactly what I needed, thanks!